Given the primes, how many numbers are there?
I have a concrete question and a more abstract version of the same. There are lots of theorems that take information on the number of elements and translate it to information on the primes; I’m looking to go the other way.
Abstract: I have an arithmetic semigroup generated by a collection of “primes” which have a known distribution function. What information do I need (e.g., about the small primes) to find the number of elements with norm at most $x$, and what is this?
Concrete: The primes are the odd primes $p$ of the natural numbers, and their valuations are $|p| = p/2$. Hence there are $\sim 2x/\log x$ primes up to $x$. How many elements are there up to $x$?

Aren't you just counting odd numbers, then?

@QiaochuYuan No, because the valuations are different. 27 < 15.

It is hard to figure what you mean there are lots of theorems for. Can you give us examples?

Also, "the primes are the odd primes..." It is entirely unclear what you mean by that. What do you mean by the word "valuation?"

Is it the case that the “primes” are literally the real numbers of the form $\frac p2$ where $p$ is an odd prime? so that for example $(\frac32)^2 \frac52$ is one the elements? I too am trying to make sense of “valuations”.

@GregMartin I guess it doesn’t really matter what you call the primes; I call them 3, 5, 7, 11, etc. The valuations are 3/2, 5/2, and so on.

So the numbers with valuations less than 5 are (in order) 1, 3, 9, 5, 27, and 15; 81 has a valuation just over 5. So $\pi(5)=6$ (up to choice of notation).

@ThomasAndrews The abstract prime number theorem, the Beurling generalized prime number theorem, etc. I’m not an expert.

For an introduction to abstract analytic number theory see Knofpmacher's book, cf. here and here. $\ \ $

@Charles If you're going to make this distinction between a prime/element and its valuation, then you'll need to be more specific about your counting functions. Are you counting primes up to $x$, or primes whose valuations go up to $x$? elements up to $x$, or elements whose valuations go up to $x$? Is an element a product of primes or a product of valuations? If the former, is the valuation of a product of primes equal to the product of the valuations of the primes?

@GregMartin: Given that there are ~2x/log x primes with valuation up to x (or you can use more precise estimates), and given whatever other useful information you need (e.g., a product over the primes), what can you deduce about the counting function of the elements up to valuation x? The element I'm calling 27 (you can call it whatever you like) has valuation 27/8 so it's included in what I'm calling $\pi(4)$.

@BillDubuque I have a copy of his Abstract Analytic Number Theory beside me, but I'm having trouble finding something applicable. (I don't know the theory at all, I assume it's covered somewhere.) At first blush it looks like Axiom C applies ($C=2,\kappa=1,\nu=-1$) but it doesn't -- that's for additive arithmetical semigroups, and as an additive arithmetical semigroup it has $\delta(p)=\log(p/2)$ and so $\pi_G^*(x)\sim2e^x/x.$

To state the question more clearly, we are interested in
$$
\#\{ n\in\Bbb N,\, n\text{ odd}\colon n/2^{\Omega(n)} \le x\}
$$
where $\Omega(n)$ is the number of prime factors of $n$ counted with multiplicity. There is probably a standard method for attacking this type of problem directly (compare for example to classical results for $\#\{n\colon \phi(n)\le x\}$). But to orient ourselves, we can proceed by writing
$$
\#\{ n\in\Bbb N,\, n\text{ odd}\colon n/2^{\Omega(n)} \le x\} = 1 + \sum_{w=1}^\infty \#\{ n\in\Bbb N,\, n\text{ odd}\colon \Omega(n) = w,\, n \le 2^wx \}.
$$
Without the restriction to $n$ odd, this simply references the classical Selberg–Sathe result
$$
\#\{ n\le y\colon \Omega(n)=w\} \sim G\biggl( \frac{w-1}{\log\log y} \biggr) \frac{y(\log\log y)^{w-1}}{(w-1)!\log y}
$$
where
$$
G(z) = \frac1{\Gamma(z+1)} \prod_p \biggl( 1-\frac zp\biggr)^{-1} \biggl( 1-\frac1p \biggr)^z.
$$
We would then get a sum like
$$
\sum_{w=1}^\infty G\biggl( \frac{w-1}{\log\log y} \biggr) \frac{2^wx(\log\log x)^{w-1}}{(w-1)!\log x}
$$
(in practice $\log(2^wx)$ is close enough to $\log x$) which could be analyzed by standard means; indeed, the maximal summand occurs near $w\approx 2\log\log x$, in a region where the $G()$ value is basically constant, and we'd simply get the series for $\approx G(2) \frac x{\log x} e^{2\log\log x} \approx G(2) x\log x$.
I recommend going to a treatment of the Selberg–Sathe result (Montgomery & Vaughan Section 7.4, or Tenenbaum Chapter 2 Section 6.1) and modifying the method to restrict to odd numbers. One should be able to get an asymptotic formula of size $x\log x$, with the right leading constant even. [Technical note: the Selberg–Sathe result only holds as stated uniformly for $w\le(2-\delta)\log\log x$, which is just short of what we need. However, when restricted to odd integers, the range of uniformity will extend to $w\le(3-\delta)\log\log x$.]
